# Applying CSS on a subString using DOM

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the JS code in which I am splitting a String using ":" . So a String given by:

Habit #1: Have you established dedicated business checking account(s)?

Would split into:

*[0]=Habit #1
and
[1]=Have you established dedicated business checking account(s)?*

Now I want to apply CSS to [0].

```
 titles=document.getElementsByClassName("title");    
            for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
            titles[i].innerHTML.split(":")[0].style.cssText="color:aqua;";
            }
```

Any modification you guys suggest to the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the fist part of the string like so:

```
var titles=document.getElementsByClassName("title");
for(var i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
    var blueFoo = titles[i].innerHTML.split(":")[0];
    var text = titles[i].innerHTML;
    var newHTML = text.replace(blueFoo,'<span style = "color:blue">' + blueFoo + '</span>');
    titles[i].innerHTML = newHTML;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
var titles=document.getElementsByClassName("title");  
titles= "<span>" + titles;
titles=titles.replace(":", ":</span">);
document.getElementsByClassName("title").innerHtml = titles;
```

I think this could work.

Comment: and don't forget the to add the class to the <span>

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot but Jad's answer worked just perfect.

Comment: No problem. I didn't mention the fact that it is an array. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap the first characters to the ":" with a `<span class="">` and give them a css class.

`<p><span class="blue">Habit #1:</span> Have you ... </p>`

Mike

Comment: i think that too, but I was wondering if there is any other way than that.

Comment: But this text is coming from an XML file. :) So wrapping would not be a good choice

Comment: You can extract the code using javascript. Then modify and replace the code with .innerHTML